# I cannot add users or otherwise control PostgreSQL 15 using openSUSE Tubleweed (updated recently)

Tags: opensuse, postgresql

I just switched workstations and installed openSUSE Tumbleweed and PostgreSQL 15 using the postgresql database repo.

Details:
Kernel: 6.3.4-1-default arch: x86_64 bits: 64 Desktop: LXQt
v: 1.3.0 Distro: openSUSE Tumbleweed 20230608

PostgreSQL 15.3 (http://download.opensuse.org/repositories/server:/database:/postgresql/openSUSE_Tumbleweed/x86_64/postgresql15-15.3-24.9.x86_64.rpm to be specific). All the PostgreSQL code is from that repo.

Things tried and failed:

Running initdb as root:
`initdb: error: cannot be run as root initdb: hint: Please log in (using, e.g., "su") as the (unprivileged) user that will own the server process.`

Running it as myself didn't work, of course, since PostgreSQL doesn't know me from Adam.

Following the instructions on the [openSUSE PostgreSQL](https://en.opensuse.org/SDB:PostgreSQL)   page:
Changing the installed postgresql login privledges and attempting to `su postgresql` -- it complained that `su: user posgresql does not exist or the user entry does not contain all the required fields`

I also tried to be clever and, as root, added:

```
local    all    kevin   trust
```

to `/var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf`, which `postgresql.service` disliked to the degree it threw a tantrum and refused to start until I commented out the offending line, and then started up again without a hicup.

Sort of beating my head against this one.

I also tried **pgadmin4**, but that has never worked AFAIK.  Get some odd, seeming intractable, Python errors.  I haven't even touched **pip** so it can't be my fault, this time.

I checked and all of the PostgreSQL packages are from the same repo.

I don't recall these problems when I have set it up before.  I have screwed things up, but nothing that wasn't easily fixed.

Do I delete and recreate postgresql user?
What am I missing?

Comment: You should only need to run `systemctl start postgresql.service` to bring it up initially. Then from root, `sudo -u postgres psql` to access it. If that does not work, then you have borked the install.

Comment: You are correct, that is all I _should_ have to do.  It doesn't not, however, suffice, as PostgreSQL is quite particular about separation of responsibilities between the sysadmin and DBA.  I think this is a very good, if not essential, security measure-- **except when the only user of the database is the person whose desktop it is installed in.**

Comment: You are incorrect. The DB does not get installed  via any person of any desktop. If you installed it via yast then it will always be available by doing `sudo -u postgres psql` since `postgres` is the database superuser.